# Custom style tooltip and binding to button WPF with code xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, binding, tooltip

I would like to create a style for the tooltip and use it always binding to each button. 
I can only do so from XAML?

I have done this for now:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">

                        <Grid Width="200" Height="Auto" MinHeight="80">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="{Binding Path=TitleTT}"/>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Path=ImageTT}" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="2"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                               Text="{Binding Path=DescriptionTT}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Now, I want to build a button in another user control.

What should I do? 
What's wrong? why can not join anything?

Thanks for the help.

Code Button:

```
    <Button  Name="button_conf" Content="{DynamicResource Button_Confirm}"  Margin="18,10"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Click="button_conf_Click">
                    <Button.ToolTip>
<ToolTip Style=ToolTip TitleTT="{DynamicResource ToolTip_title__confirm_defsce}"
ImageTT="/Images/xsd.jpg" DescriptionTT="The button confirm....:"/>

                    </Button.ToolTip>
                </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see at least the following two typos:

1.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ToolTip}" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}"
```

should be

```
<Style x:Key="ToolTipStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}"
```

Of course, you can use another name than `ToolTipStyle`.

2.

```
<ToolTip Style=ToolTip
```

should be

```
<ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle}"
```

Apart from that, the properties `TitleTT`, `ImageTT` and `DescriptionTT` do not exist on the `ToolTip` control.

Comment: Ok thanks. How I must add the propierties? Via code or into xaml?

Comment: Write your own class (e.g. called `ToolTipData`) with three public properties called `TitleTT`, `ImageTT` and `DescriptionTT`. Then, pass it to the button like this: `<Button.ToolTip><local:ToolTipData TitleTT="{DynamicResource ToolTip_title__confirm_defsce}"
ImageTT="/Images/xsd.jpg" DescriptionTT="The button confirm....:"/></Button.ToolTip>`. Furthermore, do not use a specific style for the ToolTip class, but define a `DataTemplate` for the `ToolTipInfo` type instead; as content, the DataTemplate would contain the Grid of the Style you wrote.